# Kendo grid column/filter menu disappears after using datepicker

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In my Kendo grid I have a data set that includes a date. The date is filterable and includes the built-in date picker.

When you click the date picker and subsequently pick at date from the calendar pop-up, the cursor is inevitably below the original column pop-up menu that shows the date-picker icon and input field.

Therefore, the pop-up disappears before you can submit the filter query and requires you to go back into the column menu, select filter, where you will see the date that was previously chosen.

Then you can press submit and it will filter on the date.

This behavior is quite annoying and I was wondering how I could keep the original column menu pop-up displayed so the user can then click submit. As it stands, the only way to do this is to very quickly move the mouse back up into the original pop-up after clicking on a date!

Comment: Well, as far as code goes, I'm not doing anything fancy or outside of basic Kendo settings; my date column is being defined with "filterable:true" and the field is being set to type: "date" within the Kendo "schema: model: fields:" array. What I'm saying is I think it works as expected, it just seems like a bug in the design that I'm trying to find a way around. It would probably be easier if I had actually programmed the datepicker, but since it's auto-magically being imlpemented by Kendo due to my column being a date and filterable, it's more difficult to pin down.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/AsEtoDik/2 you can see the problem here. any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [kendogrid filter menu closing on mouseleave](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20736235/kendogrid-filter-menu-closing-on-mouseleave)